# Ошибка обращения к объекту

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Есть фрагмент кода:

```
public String getInstallPath () {
    String commandLinePath = CommandLineSettings.getSettings().getInstallDir();
    if (commandLinePath != null && !commandLinePath.isEmpty()) {
        return commandLinePath;
    } else {
        return getProperty("installPath", OSUtils.getDefInstallPath());
    }
}
```

Здесь есть обращение к `getSettings()`, который определен как:

```
@Getter
private static CommandLineSettings settings;

static {
    settings = new CommandLineSettings();
}
```

При попытке получить объект появляется ошибка `Cannot resolve method 'getSettings()'`. Как это можно поправить? Почему происходит такая проблема?

Comment: Укажите что за ошибка.

Comment: Указал, спасибо

Comment: Подозреваю, что это аннотация от [Project Lombok](https://projectlombok.org/), попробуйте поставить [плагин](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6317) ([github](https://github.com/mplushnikov/lombok-intellij-plugin)).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Не знаю что делает аннотация `@Getter`, поэтому предложу обычный вариант написания геттера для статического поля класса:

```
private static CommandLineSettings settings;

static {
    settings = new CommandLineSettings();
}

public static CommandLineSettings getSetting() {return settings;}
```

Пользоваться также как вы и пытались:

```
CommandLineSettings settings = CommandLineSettings.getSettings();
```